# MongoDB -Query documents where nested array fields is equal to some value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a JSON object:

```
{
  "ownershipSheetB": {
    "lrUnitShares": [{
            "description": "blabla1",
            "lrOwners": [{
                    "lrOwnerId": 35780527,
                    "name": "somename1",
                    "address": "someadress1",
                    "taxNumber": "12345678910"
                }
            ],
            "lrUnitShareId": 29181970,
            "subSharesAndEntries": [],
            "orderNumber": "1"
        }, {
            "description": "blabla2",
            "lrOwners": [{
                    "lrOwnerId": 35780528,
                    "name": "somename2",
                    "address": "someadress2",
                    "taxNumber": "12345678911"
                }
            ],
            "lrUnitShareId": 29181971,
            "subSharesAndEntries": [],
            "orderNumber": "2"
        }
    ],
    "lrEntries": []
  }
}
```

I would like to query all documents that have `taxNumber` field equal to some string (say "12345678911" from the example above).

I have tried this query:

```
{"ownershipSheetB.lrUnitShares": { "lrOwners": {"taxNumber": "12345678910"}}}
```

but it returns no documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1: With dot notation**

```
db.collection.find({
  "ownershipSheetB.lrUnitShares.lrOwners.taxNumber": "12345678910"
})
```

[Demo Solution 1 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TlTbz5kLv5d)

---

**Solution 2: With `$elemMatch`**

```
db.collection.find({
  "ownershipSheetB.lrUnitShares": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "lrOwners": {
        $elemMatch: {
          "taxNumber": "12345678910"
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Demo Solution 2 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sgA925fKa79)